# What allows dividing equations in 1D finite potential well?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

So I was reading the [lecture notes of 8.04](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2016/lecture-notes/MIT8_04S16_LecNotes11.pdf) at MIT on the classic finite potential well problem of QM, until I reach this part in page 8:

> Let us finally complete the construction. We must impose the continuity of the wavefunction and the continuity of $\psi'$ at $x=a$. Using the expressions for $\psi$ for $x<a$ and for $x>a$ these conditions give
>   \left.
>   \begin{array}{l}
> \psi\ \text{continuous at } x=a:&\implies&\cos(ka)&=&Ae^{-\kappa a}\\
> \psi'\ \text{continuous at } x=a:&\implies&-k\sin(ka)&=&-\kappa Ae^{-\kappa a}&\tag{2.32}\\
> \end{array}
>   **Dividing the second equation by the first** we eliminate the constant $A$ and find a second relation between $k$ and $\kappa$! This is exactly what is needed. The result is
>   $$k\tan ka = \kappa\rightarrow ka\tan ka=\kappa a \rightarrow \xi = \eta \tan\eta \tag{2.33}$$

This is only for the symmetric solutions, but I have the same question for the antisymmetric solutions. My question is about the highlighted part. Why are we allowed to divide the 2 equations like that, without risking making new solutions? As I remember from [this Math.StackExchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2836379/269726), dividing can make new solutions appear.

So what did I miss when studying this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not dividing by zero, so it's fine. The cosine may not obviously be non-zero, but it's equated to an exponential, which obviously is non-zero.

Comment: But I think the problem happens even when both sides are non-zero. As stated in the [Math.StackExchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2836379/269726), the example of $$\left\{ \begin{array} { l } { x = 1} \\ { y = 1 } \end{array} \right.$$ dividing x by y gives $x=y$, which yields infinite solutions.

Comment: @Doe It is great to be careful with this stuff, but that example is flawed. Of course $x=y$ has infinite solutions, but we already know $x=1$ and $y=1$, so there is still only one solution. The link even says this too. Go back and look at the accepted answer more carefully.

Comment: @AaronStevens But what I'm saying is that dividing gives a system that is not equivalent to the previous one; they give different solutions. I'm saying (2.33) possibly is not equivalent to (2.32) in the question I posted above

Comment: @J.Doe Sometimes you have to obtain something that's not equivalent to what you started with. That usually happens when you obtain $k$ equations from $n$ with $n>k$. However, as long as you don't forget what you knew before, you shouldn't falsely conclude things are possible that aren't really.

Comment: @Doe J.G. is right, and this is explained in the link you reference. You can't divide the equations and then only look at the new result. You can get rid of any "new" solutions by only picking the ones that are consistent with the original equations.

Comment: Indeed. But I don't see them checking the solutions of $\eta ^ { 2 } + \xi ^ { 2 } = z _ { 0 } ^ { 2 } , \quad \xi = \eta \tan \eta , \quad \xi , \eta > 0$ with the original one for even bound states, or how they argue the two systems are equivalent at all! What did I miss?